# How to expose a service layer to UI components

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, appfabric

We have an application in which we have created a service layer with most of the business logic and utility services (logging, exceptions, caching etc). We have to come with a way to expose this service as an API to the UI components. Here are some of our requirements:

- We would like to create multiple
  components based on the service.
- We would like third party developers
  to use our service to create their
  own components or utilize our data.
- For scalability we would like to have
  a multiple instances installed on
  different boxes. Similarly there
  could be more than an instance of the
  same UI component.

One way to expose the service layer is to host it under a REST based WCF layer.

The other way is to host the service in model layer of an ASP.Net MVC project. The UI components will be hosted in MVC projects of their own. The Javascript in the views of UI components will directly call the controllers of service project.

WCF is supposed to be very heavyweight option. On the other hand I am not too convinced with the MVC approach as I feel that this is not purpose it is meant for.

Could you please recommend me a way in Microsoft world to expose our service layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF seems to be the way to go here. Although WCF started out (in my oppinion) as a beast, it got tamed over the years with better HTTP and JSON support and less custom configuration (although still allowing you to modefy basicly every little aspect of your service).

Exposing your current service layer as a REST Service is a breeze and allows your customers/yourself to easily consume it on any device that supports HTTP.

See: http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2010/11/01/wcf-web-apis-http-your-way/

Comment: Heard that Microsoft had to come up with WCF Web API (http://wcf.codeplex.com/) because of bulkiness of standard WCF. But it is still in preview version. Is it a good idea to go for Web API if we want to release in July?

Comment: I find it hard to answer your question. I player a litle bit  with the Web API and i already love it but i cant really tell you much about its stability etc. First of all, my point for providing the link is just to show you how WCF can also act as a lightweight service layer while still containing its full power. I surely recommend going with WCF. Now for choosing the Web API or not, if your considering it then i recommend to launch a new question on this site

Comment: Oh i see your other comment about the bulkiness of standard WCF. Good news! with .NET 4.0 you get a default configuration out of the box intergrated in WCF, the bulkiness is still there but i think with the default config and all the resources out there you will be able to survive

Answer (score 4):

Models are not services. Models are POCOs that hold data.

You can expose your service through a WCF Service, and let your ASP.NET MVC app consume it. If you're always sure that the service will run on the same box as the client app, you can use named pipes for transport -- then the overhead of WCF is minimal, compared to the advantages.

Comment: thanks for your reply. well it is a very important requirement to be able to host service layer hosted on multiple boxes for scalability. so named pipes is not an option. I heard that microsoft has a beta version of minified wcf version only for Web and REST. Are you aware of such a product from MS?

Comment: Heard that Microsoft had to come up with WCF Web API (http://wcf.codeplex.com/) because of bulkiness of standard WCF. But it is still in preview version. Is it a good idea to go for Web API if we want to release in July?

Comment: Apparently it's still in beta, so for a July release it seems imprudent to use it.

Still, you don't need to sugarcoat WCF. It's a powerful platform and the 4.0 version is easy to use if you stick to the basics. It only takes a few minutes to create a WCF service if you don't have special needs such as data streaming or data encryption.

If you don't need to do bulk inserts etc., you can also use WCF Data Services. This is a WCF layer on top of an Entity Framework model that then exposes that model using OData (combination of REST and AtomPub). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106

Answer (score 1):

WCF seems to be the direction that Microsoft is headed for this and for good reason.  WCF services are the best option here because you mentioned third-party development support.  Because these web services are defined by a WSDL, they are cross platform and can be consumed by non .NET applications.

It perfectly seperates your service layer to be consumed by ANY components.